# Variables contain 0 and do not take in user input

Tags: python

I try to calculate several properties of students:

- the amount of students
- the sum of the marks of the students
- the lowest, the average and the highest mark they received.

Yet, the variable `mark` only shows 0.

How can I solve this problem using function but not max() and min()?

```
mark = 0

a = 0
student = 0
a = int(input("Enter Marks :"))

def maxx():
    maxx = 0
    for i in range(1, a):
        if a> maxx :
            maxx = a
    return maxx

def minn():
    minn = 0
    for i in range(1, a):
        if a < minn :
            minn = a
    return minn

while (a >= 0):
    mark = mark + a
    student = student + 1
    a = int(input("Enter Marks :"))

print("Exit")
print("Total students :", student)
print ("The total marks is:", mark)

average = mark/student

print ("The average marks is:", average)
print("The max marks is :", maxx())
print("The min marks is :", minn())
```

Comment: your function use the global `a` - your while loop loops until `a` is smaller then 0. Your function uses ranges from 1 to the current `a` .. how many numbers are there in an exclusive  `range` of `1` to _less then zero_ if you are only allowed to increment .... You might want to use a debugger or print - statements. This: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/  and that:  [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) might help you fix your errors.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, actually, yes. I don't really understand what's the point of these functions now...

Comment: You have different problems in the code, store marks in a list and use it for looping in your functions (**maxx** and **minn**). Be sure to pass the list for argument of the function like so `maxx(marks)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a lot of problems. One of them is

```
for i in range(1, a):
```

This part makes no sense if you want a min or max value. You need to iterate over a list of grades instead.
`mark` and `student` are also unnecessary considering they can be replaced by `sum` and `len` respectively.
The entire code seems to lack a proper structure. Here's an example implementation. If you are not allowed to use `sum` or `len`, you may bring your own `mark` and `student` method back, but try not to make a mess and keep it readable:

```
def maxx(grades):
    if (not grades): # if empty, we let the caller know 
        return None

    res = grades[0]  # we know the list is not empty

    for i in grades:
        if i > res:
            res = i
    return res

def minn(grades):
    if (not grades):
        return None

    res = grades[0]

    for i in grades:
        if i < res:
            res = i
    return res

def main():
    grades = []  # list of grades

    while (True):
        grade = int(input("Enter Mark: "))
        if (grade < 0): break
        grades.append(grade)

    student_cnt = len(grades)
    total = sum(grades)

    print("Exit")
    print("Total students :", student_cnt)
    print("The total marks is:", total)

    print ("The average marks is:", total / student_cnt)
    print("The max marks is :", maxx(grades))
    print("The min marks is :", minn(grades))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Input/Output:

```
Enter Mark:  30
Enter Mark:  20
Enter Mark:  10
Enter Mark:  40
Enter Mark:  -1
Exit
Total students : 4
The total marks is: 100
The average marks is: 25.0
The max marks is : 40
The min marks is : 10
```